# How can I validate the length only when the field is not empty?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have one text box, which I want to check for min-length, but it should check only when some text is there.

If someone has left that textbox empty, then it should not check for min-length.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean, that the text box can be left empty, then this may be your answer:

```
$("#your_text_box").rules("add", {
   required: false, // this means the field can be left empty
   minlength: 2
});
```

Using this, validator will skip this text box if it is empty.
Hope this helps!

Comment: your code does not work if I just put 1 space, what is the logic behind it?

Comment: Whta do you mean?
If I'm correct there is no built in trim in validator, so one space is one character, which means the box is not empty, minlegth check fires, less then 2 characters => fail.

Comment: Sweet. This solution worked for me. I have the validator setup for emails and url's so didn't need the minlength in this particular case, but that is how I'll handle arbitrary text fields. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
var yourLimit = 1;    
var myLength = $("#eTextBox").val().length;
    if(myLength>=yourLimit){
       //do whatever you want
    }
```

Hope the above code will help you.